# htaccess redirect all routes start with xxx query string

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I use the below code in `.htaccess` for redirecting the subdomain of `Domain1`(wordpress) to `Domain2`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^learn.Domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.learn.Domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/\Domain2\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

All is OK.

But my product downloads link that email to user for download started with this in `woocommerce`:

```
learn.Domain1.com/?download_file=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I use this `cond` redirect except for downloads URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?download_file=
```

But this does not work!

How can I fix it?

Comment: Veeery thanks. I use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^download_file=(.*)` . please add this to answer .

Comment: True, that should have probably been an answer from the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

- the `^` in the regex means "starts by" and your URI doesn't start by the query parameters
- as stated in [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), `REQUEST_URI` doesn't include request parameters, try with `QUERY_STRING`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^download_file=(.*)
```

**NOTE**: because of the `^`, this will work only if the parameter `download_file` is the first, if it's not the case, you can use :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)download_file=(.*)
```